# Finding the probability mass function

Tags: probability, statistics

How can I find the probability mass function of the following example. A pair of dice is tossed if the sum of the two outcomes is prime number the dice are tossed again and the process repeated. If the sum of the two dice is not a prime number the sum is recorded.

A. Determine the probability mass function
B. Determine the expected value for the sum

So I think my random variable $X$ has to be a non prime number.
So I have

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
X & P(X) \\ \hline
4 & 3/36 \\ \hline
6 & 5/36 \\ \hline
8 & 5/36 \\ \hline
9 & 4/36 \\ \hline
10&  3/36 \\ \hline
12&  1/36 \\ \hline
\end{array}

But I am not sure how to find the pmf

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are conditioning on the sum not being prime; in the conditional universe, all samples compatible with the conditioning event have the same *relative* probabilities as in the unconditional model. You calculated these probabilities for the unconditional model, now all you need is to renormalize them so that they add up to 1.

PS: From the probabilities in your question (I did not check them), the new common denominator is $3+5+5+4+3+1=21$, so in the conditional model for example $P(X=4)=3/21$ (same numerator, new denominator), etc.

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: @FernandoMartinez I've updated the answer.

Comment: and then the expected value is sum of the random variable times probability I think,

Comment: @FernandoMartinez yes, by definition of the expected value.